# MediaRouter connect second time

Tags: android, chromecast, presentation

I am using Android's MediaRouter / Presentation API (the support.v7 version).

Everything works fine so far. The only thing that doesn't is:

When I quit my activity (e.g.teardown & remove the callbacks), everything still works fine.

However, when starting this activity (the previous mediarouter-activity was forcefully finished, thus onPause/onDestroy was called FOR SURE => so those callbacks in there are gone too, as also shown in my debug messages) again at some later point in time, the callbacks get created and added and everything. Just, that there is no more onRouteAdded called, only onProviderChanged (With the default provider and  thus useless).

It does always work like that (with wifi display [miracast], emulated secondary display, chromecast secondary display..). Are there any resolutions which are not in the examples?

Would you like to look at some code? Which special cases? (Can't post it all..)

I couldn't find anything so far, thanks for your help, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `getSelectedRoute()`instead of the RouteInfo (which is provided by the callbacks) did the job for me.

```
MediaRouter.RouteInfo selectedRoute = getHelper().getMediaRouter().getSelectedRoute();
if(provider != null && getCurrentRoute() != null && getCurrentRoute().equals(selectedRoute)){
    Log.d(TAG, "only provider changes, dont do anything");
    return false;
}

if (selectedRoute != null) {
    setCurrentRoute(selectedRoute);
}

return updateContents();
```

this is definetly weird (as the rest of the code looks exactly as in the provided google android developer samples), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Google Cast sample app to support MediaRouter.Callback: 
https://github.com/googlecast/CastPresentation-android

Then I'm getting the onRouteAdded called every time.

Comment: did you do it with the (MediaRouter) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE); or via the (support method) MediaRouter.getInstance(Context) ? 
Might be a difference there.?

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem was resolved over 1 year ago, but probably it isn't the perfect solution. Maybe it will be useful for somebody else.

I had similar problem with exactly the same symptoms (no more onRouteAdded called). In my situation it was caused by improperly implemented deactivation of MediaRouter: to deactivate it properly you should not only remove all of callbacks, but select default MediaRoute as well.

```
if (!mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute().isSelected()) {
    mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute().select();
}
```